# dart recursive_getter info warning

Tags: dart, recursion, lint

Insert in the dart pad

```
void main() {
  print(Foo().bar);
}

class Foo {
  bool get bar => bar;
}
```

and you will get the warning `The getter 'bar' recursively returns itself. Try changing the value being returned.` (From the recursive_getters lint)

I'm wondering why this is only a INFO-level linter warning. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out myself. Insert

```
void main() {
  print(Fu().gazi);
}


class Fu {
  int bla = 1;
  bool get gazi {
    if(bla < 10) {
      bla++;
      return gazi;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and you get the same linter warning. The difference being: The example from the question runs into a runtime error, the example here does not - it's probably not what getters are for (you'd use a function for this), but it works. And thus anything more than an INFO-level warning might be seen as exaggerated here.